# How to put bquote superscript in between two strings in ggplot axes

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to get this string `Linear Prediction of Protein (mg/ gm^-1 per kg)` in my ggplot y axis. I tried the below syntax, but could not get as desired. What am I missing here?

```
p + ylab(bquote('Linear Prediction of Protein\n (mg/' ~gm^-1 'per kg soil'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a version you could use to split the lines of text

```
 + ylab(expression(atop("Linear Prediction of Protein", paste("(mg/g", m^-1, ") per kg soil"))))
```